# Using std::bind and std::function with a class member causes the callback to use an old object reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, std-function, stdbind

This is confusing, but basically what I've got is a class that has a callback function using the c++11 `std::function` and `std::bind`.  Everything is working fine.  But when I need to reset everything by reassigning the object, it seems the new object isn't getting all of the references correct.  Here is an example program that demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass() = default;

    void RegisterCallback(std::function<void(void)> f) {
        callback = f;
    }

    void PrintThings() {
        callback();
    }

    std::function<void(void)> callback;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {
        list_of_things.push_back("thing1");
        list_of_things.push_back("thing2");
        list_of_things.push_back("thing3");
        list_of_things.push_back("thing4");

        other_class.RegisterCallback(std::bind(&MyClass::MyFunction, this));
    }

    void PrintThings() {
        MyFunction();
        other_class.PrintThings();
    }

    void MyFunction() {
        auto a = this;
        for (auto& thing: list_of_things)
        {
            std::cout << thing << std::endl;
        }
    }

    OtherClass other_class;
    std::list<std::string> list_of_things;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass my_class;
    my_class.PrintThings();
    my_class = MyClass();
    my_class.PrintThings();
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

It's a little confusing, but basically if you compile with debug flags and step through it, you'll find that the first time we call `my_class.PrintThings()` it prints them twice; once for the `MyFunction()` call and once for the `other_class.PrintThings()` call which calls `MyFunction` as a callback.  Then, we replace the object with `my_class = MyClass()`, invoking a new constructor and all that.  When we step through, we find that it prints the list on the call to `MyFunction` but *not* on the call to `other_class.PrintThings()`.  `MyFunction` has a variable `a` that I'm using to see the address of the object; the second time through `a` has a different address depending on whether `MyFunction` was called as a callback from `OtherClass`.

In this example, the offending ghost object just has an empty list (presumably as a result of being destroyed) but in the actual program where I encountered this, it was filled with garbage memory and caused a segmentation fault.  I also noticed some weird behavior with my debugger; when it reached the ghost object it wouldn't just step in or over, it would skip the function unless I put a breakpoint inside there.

What is going on? Why isn't the callback bound properly the second time through? Is there something special I need to do in the destructor or something? Am I missing some fundamental understanding of function pointers or `std::bind`?

Comment: `my_class = MyClass()` invokes a copy, but you don't have a custom assignment operator which will reconnect other_class's callback with the assigned-to object. You are seeing undefined behaviour. If you need this kind of callback mechanism within the same object you should use a pimpl idiom

Comment: please add the expected and actual output, also i believe your example could be shorter

Comment: @RichardHodges Actually, the compiler-generated copy assignment operator will copy all members of the class, thus copying the OtherClass instance and thus also copying its std::function object. Plus, calling an uninitialized std::function is not undefined behavior, it's supposed to throw a std::bad_function_call exception.

Comment: @fkorsa it will copy a std::function which is referencing a member function of an instance which will not exist after the copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is going on?

Undefined behaviour

> Why isn't the callback bound properly the second time through?

Because you created a new OtherClass as part of assigning a new MyClass to my_class. You have not initialised its callback.

> Is there something special I need to do in the destructor or something?

In the destructor, assignment and copy constructors. This is because you're storing the address of "myself" in yourself. This is all well and good until the object changes address, which it will when copied. Note that in the code below, all three are taken care of by the use of a smart_ptr.

One solution is to refactor MyClass to use the pimpl idiom. i.e. the class is a wrapper around an implementation whose address never changes.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass() = default;

    void RegisterCallback(std::function<void(void)> f) {
        callback = f;
    }

    void PrintThings() {
        callback();
    }

    std::function<void(void)> callback;
};


class MyClass
{
    struct Impl
    {
        Impl()
        {
            list_of_things.push_back("thing1");
            list_of_things.push_back("thing2");
            list_of_things.push_back("thing3");
            list_of_things.push_back("thing4");
        }

        void MyFunction() 
        {
            for (auto& thing: list_of_things)
            {
                std::cout << thing << std::endl;
            }
        }

        void PrintThings() {
            MyFunction();
            other_class.PrintThings();
        }

        OtherClass other_class;
        std::list<std::string> list_of_things;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl_;

public:
    MyClass() 
    : impl_(std::make_unique<Impl>())
    {
        impl_->other_class.RegisterCallback(std::bind(&Impl::MyFunction, impl_.get()));
    }

    void PrintThings() {
        impl_->PrintThings();
    }


};

int main()
{
    MyClass my_class;
    my_class.PrintThings();
    my_class = MyClass();
    my_class.PrintThings();
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
thing1
thing2
thing3
thing4
thing1
thing2
thing3
thing4
thing1
thing2
thing3
thing4
thing1
thing2
thing3
thing4
done
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized my mistake in bed ten minutes after I posted this.  In my case, I will probably move the `RegisterCallback` function out of the constructor and into an `init` function, but your solution could be useful in other cases.